# python manage.py migrate giving error main()

Tags: python

Here is the error:

```
C:\Users\ric\Desktop\Private\PoS\with intructione\pos_4 - Copy\pos>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ric\Desktop\Private\PoS\with intructione\pos_4 - Copy\pos\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\ric\Desktop\Private\PoS\with intructione\pos_4 - Copy\pos\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\ric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)....
 from flask import jsonify
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Answer (score 0):

> from flask import jsonify ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

So the short answer is "you don't have flask installed"